# Get screenshot of android Device

Tags: c#, android, appium, ironpython

I try to get screenshot of android device using appium since there is no solution with appium to get video/see app on real time.

I have function of C# to get image (screenshot)

```
public Image GetImages()
    {
        Image screen_shot = null;
        try
        {
            if (driverAndroid == null)
            {
                return screen_shot;
            }
            var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driverAndroid).GetScreenshot();
            var ms = new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray);
            screen_shot = Image.FromStream(ms);
            ms.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return screen_shot;
    }
```

and I try to call it using ironpython

```
class HelloWorldForm(Form):

    def __init__(self):
        app = test()
        Form.__init__(self)
        pictureBox = PictureBox()
        image = app.GetImages()
        pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        pictureBox.Image = image
        pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        self.Controls.Add(pictureBox)
        self.Show()



Application.EnableVisualStyles()
form = HelloWorldForm()
Application.Run(form)
```

I can get only 1st image for now, I put it in while function but it does not work.
Any solution or modification on the code so that I can get screenshot on real time, like a video.